Exercise 16. 3A Linear Algebra Done Right
Exercise: Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional with $\dim V \gt 1$. Prove that there exist
$S,T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ such that $ST \neq TS$.
I had been trying to prove it, when I gave up, I looked for someone's answer here, and found this:
Composition of Linear Maps satisfying $ST\neq TS$.
I really liked it, but I know that I would never intuitively think of that, so with his idea, I thought of my own example and I want to know if it is correct, since I am a little unsure about it.
Since $V$ is finite-dimensional, consider $\dim V = n\ge 2$, and $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ a basis for $V$.
Consider the linear transformations $S$ and $T$ defined by
$$Tv_{j}= \begin{cases}
2v_{j+1} & \text{if } j\lt n, \\
3v_{1} & \text{if } j=n \\
\end{cases}$$
$$Sv_{j}=\begin{cases}
2v_{j} & \text{if } j \text{ is odd}, \\
3v_{j} & \text{if } j \text{ is even} \\
\end{cases}$$
If $v \in V$, $v = \alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+...+\alpha_nv_n$. Assume, without loss of generality, that $n$ is even. Then:
$$Tv=2\alpha_1v_2+2\alpha_2v_3+...+2\alpha_{n-1}v_n+3\alpha_nv_1$$
$$S(Tv)=6\alpha_1v_2+4\alpha_2v_3+...+6\alpha_{n-1}v_n+6\alpha_nv_1$$
and
$$Sv=2\alpha_1v_1+3\alpha_2v_2+...+2\alpha_{n-1}v_{n-1}+3\alpha_nv_n$$
$$T(Sv)=4\alpha_1v_2+6\alpha_2v_3+...+4\alpha_{n-1}v_n+9\alpha_nv_1$$
therefore $ST\neq TS$.

Why don you just say that,since  $S(Tv_1)=S(2v_2)=6v_2$ and $T(Sv_1))=T(2v_1)=2v_2$, $S\circ T\ne T\circ S$?

@JoséCarlosSantos You're right, I overcomplicated it, but... then the transformation does work  thanks.

Yes, it works, but it is much more complex than it needs to be.

@JoséCarlosSantos Can I know what your answer would have been? I still find it difficult to solve this type of exercises without going around in circles on unnecessary things.

Take any two linearly independent vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ and then take any two linear maps $S,T\colon V\longrightarrow V$ such that $S(v_1)=T(v_2)=0$, that $S(v_2)=v_1$, and that $T(v_1)=v_2$. Then $S(T(v_1))=S(v_2)=v_1$ and $T(S(v_1))=T(0)=0$. So, $S\circ T\ne T\circ S$.

As a general idea for solving such things, first examine the simplest possible case: $n=2$, and the most familiar variation of it: $V = \Bbb R^2$, where $S$ and $T$ can be treated as matrices. Now figure out the mininum that must be accomplished: $TS \ne ST$ if there is even one vector where they give different results. So we need some $v$ with $S(T(v)) \ne T(S(v))$. So we generally need vectors $x, y$ with $T(v) = x, S(v) = y$ and two more vectors $u \ne w$ with $S(x) = u, T(y) = w$. This overshoots the simplest case, but it is not hard to pick 5 vectors, then two maps with the given behavior

Once you've found a solution, at least in this case, it isn't hard to generalize it to a full solution. Then maybe simplify it by choosing $0$ as a particularly convenient value, and repetition among the vectors that do not have to be unique, thus arriving at José Carlos Santos' solution.
